# Driver for these SPI TFT displays?

Tags: display, driver

I have some old SPI TFT screens with the uncommon chipset like SPFD5408A and EPSON S1D15G10.
I want to use it as a main screen. (if possible)
Can i use/modify from the fbtft(notro) or anyway i can do to use it?